# setting value from database to multiple spinner doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to set value from array to spinner but it is working for few and not for others. Please help me out. here is my code.

```
edmORdelOF = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ed_sign_up_manf_del_of);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterItem = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterItem.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    edmORdelOF.setAdapter(adapterItem);
    System.out.println(profile.getEdmORdelOF()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterItem.getPosition(profile.getEdmORdelOF()));
    edmORdelOF.setSelection(adapterItem.getPosition(profile.getEdmORdelOF()));

    org_type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Updatesp_sign_up_manf_org_type);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Org_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    org_type.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println(profile.getD_org_type()+"....getPosition..........."+adapter.getPosition(profile.getD_org_type()));
    org_type.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(profile.getD_org_type()));


    country = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Updatesp_sign_up_country);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCountry = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.Country, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    country.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
    System.out.println(profile.getD_country()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterCountry.getPosition(profile.getD_country()));
    country.setSelection(adapterCountry.getPosition(profile.getD_country()));
```

here,i am getting value from bean object profile and trying to set that values to spinner but state doesn't get the value. sorry every one.i have change it

Comment: do you log statements print the correct value?

Comment: But as I can see, you get values not from DB, but from array in strings.xml

Comment: What spinners do work and what don't?

Comment: It is getting the correct value but it is not setting that value to spinner.

Comment: Sorry, it is getting value from array. by mistake i wrote database.sorry once again.